# Nested for loop not running in python after the first iteration

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a nested for loop which is not running after the first iteration

```
N, M = map(int, input().split())
numbers = map(int, input().split())

dic = {}
for m in range(N):
  dic.setdefault(m,[])
  for n in numbers:
      if n % N == m:
      dic[m].append(n)
print(dic)
```

The above code is generating the following result `{0: [3, 42], 1: [], 2: []}` for the sample data down bellow:

```
3 5
1 3 8 10 42
```

However I would like to get `{0: [3, 42], 1: [1, 10], 2: [8]}`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `map` returns an iterator, and you are consuming the iterator completely in the first outer loop.  You need:

```
numbers = [int(k) for k in input().split()]
```

instead of using `map`.

Comment: Or `numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))`, where the `list` builtin transforms the iterator into a list (although Tim's answer is more pythonic).

Comment: Just for the sake of giving alternatives, ```numbers = [*map(int, input().split())]``` works too.

Comment: It's an interesting debate.  I prefer the way the `map` call looks, but I've been burned just as the OP has, so I generally avoid it in favor of a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
N, M = map(int, input().split())
numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

dic = {}
for m in range(N):
    dic.setdefault(m,[])
    for n in numbers:
        print(n % N)
        if n % N == m:
            dic[m].append(n)
print(dic)
```

Comment: Which is exactly what I said.

Comment: yes.. I did not see your answer when I posted mine.. :)